# Upload PHP não envia certos arquivos

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou usando o meio básico de upload de arquivos, já que a validação da extensão e feito isoladamente. Nosso servidor está limitado a arquivos de até 100MB, porém ao testar, alguns arquivos vão normalmente, mas um arquivo com 51MB não vai. Não dá erro, apenas a página da um reload e nao envia. O código segue abaixo:

```
$arquivoNome = $_FILES['Arquivos']['name'];
$arquivoTemp = $_FILES['Arquivos']['tmp_name'];

list($arquivo, $extensao) = explode(".",$arquivoNome);
    $codificar = md5(date('h:i').$arquivo).".".$extensao;
    $dirArquivo = "uploads/pdf/";
    $upArquivo = $dirArquivo . basename($codificar);

    if(move_uploaded_file($arquivoTemp, $upArquivo)){
       // Aqui cadastro no banco 
    }
```

Muito estranho, pois os arquivos são da mesma extensão PDF, o que diferencia é o tamanho. Arquivos com 20MB por exemplo vão, mas o de 50MB não vai...

Comment: Veja se há alguma mensagem de erro no log de erros do servidor.

Comment: Aparece essa mensagem: [09-May-2016 12:35:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 51662811 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0.... mas que estranho... colocamos para 100MB

Comment: Veja se você não alterou o php.ini referente à linha de comando, ao invés do php.ini do servidor web. Tente reiniciar o servidor. Também é possível que você tenha múltiplas instalações locais do PHP (nesse caso, veja qual é o php.ini usado pelo comando `phpinfo()`).

Comment: Na verdade não temos acesso ao php.ini, pois estamos usando uma cloud. No phpinfo() está retornando upload_max_filesize 100M 100M

Comment: mas nessa linha está 8MB post_max_size

Comment: acho que é nessa linha Rodrigo. Vou alterar e retorno...

Comment: É esse o problema. A soma do tamanho de todos os arquivo tem que ser menor ou igual ao tamanho do POST. Basta ajustar a diretiva `post_max_size` para os mesmos `100M`.

Comment: Certo Rodrigo. Vou alterar aqui e retorno ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando eu precisei configurar o limite maximo de upload e não tive acesso ao php.ini resolvi configurando no htacess assim:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
   php_value post_max_size 100M
</IfModule>
```

Aqui tem uma referencia de onde você pode colocar estas configurações: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Neste caso sendo da categoria: **PHP_INI_PERDIR**, versão 5.3 ou posterior.

Comment: Perfeito Gabriel. Estava pensando exatamente como alterar caso não consiga pelo servidor rsrsrsrs.... se a gente não conseguir, iremos aproveitar seu código....

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel. Funcionou!